# Can't enable php_intl.dll in xampp php 7.3.2

Tags: php-extension

I have just uninstalled and installed xampp to upgrade both xampp and php to newer versions.  I have removed semi-colon on extension=intl and tried to change it to extension=php_intl.dll.  I changed php.ini to: 
`[intl]
intl.default_locale = en_us
; This directive allows you to produce PHP errors when some error
; happens within intl functions. The value is the level of the error produced.
; Default is 0, which does not produce any errors.
intl.error_level = E_WARNING
;intl.use_exceptions = 0`

I have 2017 C++ redistributable installed.
The directory is correct and php_intl.dll is in C:\xampp\php\ext
other ext like ldap is working.  Same directory.

And still intl is not showing as enabled in phpinfo().  Please help me enable this ext on my system.

Error Message : Mon Mar  4 15:40:43 2019] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable t
o load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\intl (The specified m
odule could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_intl.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: UPDATE: rolled back to php 7.2.15 and no error message.  Must be an issue with 7.3.2 php.